# ssh variable port from host match

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

Say I have the following config in `~./ssh/config`

```
Host server*-port
  HostName 111.111.111.111
  User share
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  Port 9%h0
```

If I do `ssh server01-port`, I want the port be `9010`. If I do `ssh server12-port`, the port should be `9120`.

Is it possible with default ssh config syntax or is there any tools suitable for that?

Comment: Are your example values wrong - should `server01-port` be 9010 and `server05-port` be 9050?   Try - `man ssh_config` - doesn't seem to suggest you can do what you want with wildcards (for the port).  Seems fairly simple in this case to cut/paste 12 configurations.

Comment: @MrR You're right, my example is wrong, the typo is fixed now. If there isn't any more concise way to do this, write all the cases is a feasible way.